# Local Storage to save state of multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I was wondering if there was a way to save multiple divs and their newly added classes within local storage?

In the below Codepen we have a main div where you can add a class, clone it, add it to the container div below and then delete the last div in the container. This process repeats.

What I'd like to do is save all the div states and their class names in local storage so that the next time the page is viewed it remembers the class names.

Any help would be appreciated...

```
  //set local storage to save state of divs (help needed)

  $(".btngreen").on("click", function () {
  $("#main").removeClass().addClass("green")
  localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'green')
  })

  $(".btnorange").on("click", function () {
  $("#main").removeClass().addClass("orange")
  localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'orange')
  })

  $(".btnyellow").on("click", function () {
  $("#main").removeClass().addClass("yellow")
  localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'yellow')
  })

  $(".clone").on("click", function () {
  $("#main").clone().removeClass("main").prependTo(".container")
  $(".container div").last().remove()
```

https://codepen.io/fuzzyduck/pen/NWzBPvG

Comment: You are overwriting the local storage key/value pair. If you want to persist the data of each div then each div needs some kind of a unique identifier.

Comment: You say local storage for a future visit but...? The page must be identical for all visitors who will visit the page...? If a modification will be made, it will be for all visitors...?

Comment: It's for a kiosk in a museum i.e. (one user only) - it will always need to be in the last saved state.

Re: the unique identifier - every time the div is cloned create a new version of itself - so not 100% sure how a unique identifier can be applied to multiple clones?

Comment: Ok but who will be able to modify it and how often...? If the modification is made by a single person then you could store it locally simply on the server for example

Comment: see a working example https://codepen.io/MordyS/pen/ExRpjNr